# Customize bootstrap datetime picker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, eonasdan-datetimepicker

[image]

I am using the datetime picker library based on bootstrap [https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/].

Everything works fine and I am looking to change a small thing around. The little clock glyphicon at the bottom-left part of the screen is not so intuitive to pick time.

Is there a way I can add some text like "pick time" just along the clock glyphicon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [icons](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#icons) option to define a custom css class for your icon and then you can write a css rule to customize "pick time" button as shown below:

```js
$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
        icons: {
            time: 'glyphicon timeWithText'
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.timeWithText:before{
    content: "\e023  pick time";
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.12.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
  <input type='text' class="form-control" />
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: It works, but the text has too much space in between words(and icon). Is there anything to solve this?